# What would be the best approach for screen sharing c#

Tags: c#, desktop, screensharing

i want to develop a small communication apps like there will be one wcf service hosted in server and one desktop client would be there. suppose two people interact in each other through wcf service. when client1 will send data to client2 then data will go to wcf service and wcf service will push the data to client2. developing basic communication application with the help of wcf service easy. i want to add one utility into our apps called screen sharing.

client1 will send his desktop screen to client2. i know it is very easy to capture desktop image and convert the whole image to byte array and then pass the byte array to client2 and client2 can convert the byte array to image and set the image to his picturebox.if i send the whole image over the network every time then performance will be bad and slow. so i need to know how people develop apps to share their screen with other and how they send minimum data over the network. i search google a lot to get actual standard though but got none.

so i request every one of this forum please discuss this issue in detail with real life concept.

### My Points are

1) just tell me how could i send the difference only between two images over the network instead of sending whole image again & again. lots of image processing library available which can be use to get the difference between two images but i do not know which one is the best and would be very faster....just take few ms to get the difference between two images.

2) after extarcting difference between two images i can send the difference over the network but on the client2 side how can i apply the difference on the present image. this is very important.

3) when picturebox will be updated frequently at client2 then a flicker may be noticable. how could i avoid this flicker rather how could i achieve the smooth change over of the images on client2 side.

the way i need the help like if it would be possible then please suggest me library with code snippet which i can use to extract the difference between two images.

also tell me what routine i can use to apply the diff on the current image at client2 side.

again tell me how could i achieve the smooth change over of the images on client2 side without flickering.

lots of scholar person visit this forum every second so i would expect good discusion in detail with pesudo code in c#. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not embark on a project to write your own [Remote Desktop Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use existing libraries first.

- [Remote Desktop Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/)
- [rdesktop.org](http://www.rdesktop.org/)
- [Remote Desktop using C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET)

Comment: can we share my screen between two pc over the internet but two pc may not in same lan or wan....then your article can show me the way i want to share my screen.

Comment: i think u did not understand what i am trying to do. i want to share screen like teamviewer logmein but not want to control keyboard or mouse of remote machine....just like to share screen. i am not looking for Remote Desktop Protocol. anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: RDP is the way to go, with or without input control. That's what every Windows screen sharing product uses, over LAN/WAN or whatever net you fancy.

Comment: RDP can be use over the internet. when we do remote desktop share or vnc then we need to provide another machine IP where we like to connect. but in case of teamviewer or logmein we do not need to know client machine IP. i like to develop apps where i can share my screen with anyone in the world without knowing their IP address

Comment: All services that connect consumers behind NAT resort to routing through the hosting service if they cannot punch a UPnP hole in the NAT. TeamViewer nor LogMeIN are no exceptions. This is TCP 101. Skype is no exception (they can use non-NAT consumers for relay/routing, that is a different story). This issue is completely orthogonal to *what is the protocol content*.